# master playbook create vms before loading inventory for bootstrapping

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have one yaml file to create vms and bootstrap the new servers?

I have a master playbook

```
---
# Master playbook for 
# - creating server
# - bootstrap server
#
- import_playbook: create_vm.yml
- import_playbook: bootsrap_vm.yml
```

import_playbook: create_vm.yml using `hosts: localhost`

import_playbook: bootsrap_vm.yml using `hosts: all`

Im using a dynamic inventory. But the bootstrap_vm.yaml does not know about the newly created servers. Is it possible to somehow update the inventory after the vms are created and before the bootstrapping starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta: refresh_inventory` was added in ansible 2.0 specifically for this type of requirement.

> `(meta: )refresh_inventory` (added in Ansible 2.0) forces the reload of the inventory, which in the case of dynamic inventory scripts means they will be re-executed. If the dynamic inventory script is using a cache, Ansible cannot know this and has no way of refreshing it (you can disable the cache or, if available for your specific inventory datasource (e.g. aws), you can use the an inventory plugin instead of an inventory script). This is mainly useful when additional hosts are created and users wish to use them instead of using the add_host module.

Add this as a task at the end or your `create_vm.yml` playbook, or in a specific play in between the 2 playbooks.

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html

Comment: Plus 1, so far I was using `add_host` module.